# Не удается преобразовать "System.Collections.Generic.List<string>" в "string"

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать вывод информации о процессоре в label1.

Но возникает ошибка

**Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.List" в "string"**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace simple
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static List<string> GetHardwareInfo(string WIN32_Class, string ClassItemField)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();

            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM " + WIN32_Class);

            try
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    result.Add(obj[ClassItemField].ToString().Trim());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            return result;
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> process = GetHardwareInfo("Win32_Processor", "Name");
            label2.Text = process;
        }
```

Почему так? Как исправить?

Comment: А немного подумать? Вот у вас есть коробка разных конфет, вы хотите отобразить ценник одной из них, ваши действия? Сейчас вы тупо пытаетесь всю коллекцию запихнуть в обычную строку (`label2.Text = process;`)... Наверно надо найти "ту самую конфету" и уже ее отображать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я создаю переменую и запрашиваю в неё значение `string CPU = GetHardwareInfo("Win32_Processor")` и хочу потом вывести это в label1 - но выходит ошибка преобразования. Я выделяю одну конфету и хочу увидеть её ценник.

Comment: Где в коде выше строка `string CPU = GetHardwareInfo("Win32_Processor")`? Я лично вижу там `List<string> process = GetHardwareInfo("Win32_Processor", "Name");`, где метод `GetHardwareInfo` является коллекцией (`List<string>`). А также я вижу `label2.Text = process;`, где вы тексту (`string`) пытаетесь указать коллекцию строк (`List<string>`). Так что в каком это таком месте вы нашли `Я выделяю одну конфету`?

Comment: Попробуйте label2.Text = process[0];

Comment: @AimonZ. Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`label2.Text = process[0]`
Стоило выбрать значение из списка.